# mongoimport for csv: "no such file or directory"; "imported 0 documents"

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a .csv file full of data into mongo on OSX. I'm opening a terminal, running `mongod` and then opening a new terminal window and running the following command

`Scotts-MacBook-Air:~ scott$ mongoimport --db myDbName --collection myCollectionName --type csv --headerline --file /Desktop/info.csv`

I've tried it many different times but am always getting the following response:

`2019-02-11T19:16:04.904-0600   Failed: open /Desktop/info.csv: no such file or directory
2019-02-11T19:16:04.905-0600    imported 0 documents`

The document is saved as Windows comma separated (.csv) format on my desktop.

Can anyone help me understand how I can get this to be accepted by mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the file as `/Desktop/info.csv`, which means that you told `mongoimport` to look for the file under a `/Desktop` folder that resides under the root directory.

I don't think this is what you intended.

Changing `/Desktop/info.csv` to `~/Desktop/info.csv` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I was connecting to remote mongo instance. Turns out you just need to add the file location and info before the remote server info.
Like
mongoimport --file=ab.csv --host=*** --name=*** --db=user --collection=demo